# JMeter load test with flash file, downloaded bytes inconsistent

Tags: flash, download, jmeter, load-testing

I'm configuring a JMeter load test for a number of pages, one of which contains a flash object. I've included a HTTP request (GET) with a direct link to the swf file, but the downloaded size does not make any sense.

First of all it fluctuates from request to request (a few bytes difference usually) and second the bytes as shown in the "View Results Table" do not match the filesize of the swf by a long shot. The actual filesize is 540386 bytes, but JMeter reports around 27100.

I want to use the "save response as MD5 hash", but I need to understand what is going on first.

How can I make sure JMeter actually retrieves the entire swf file?

I'm using Jmeter 2.10 r1533061 on Windows 7 testing an Apache webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was stupid... I had forgotten to enter a path for the request (I had only put it in the Name field). After I properly entered the path, everything was fine.